# string between two special characters impala sql

Tags: sql, impala

Hi all I am trying to write sql for selecting string between two special characters.

example: in the table, field value like 7185878969-129981041-000000 . how can I select only middle portion 129981041 without hard coding. What will be the best way to go about this?.Please provide sample code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impala has [`split_part()`](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_string_functions.html):

```
select split_part(col, '-', 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this for MySQL:**

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Column,'-',2)),'-',1))
FROM table_name;
```

**Result**:

```
129981041
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I tested but getting error like .Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 1:39 Invalid function 'SUBSTRING_INDEX'